# How can I compute whether or not a SIN number is valid using this formula?

Tags: java

My code takes a Sin number (Social Insurance Number) in the form of DDD-DDD-DDD where each D is a digit. It validates whether the format is valid, and then attempts to compute if the sin is legit by using the formula of multiplying it by 121 212 121, adding any two digit number together, and then if after being divided by 10, equals 0, it is real.

I have no idea how I can add the two digits gotten from multiplication together.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SinNumber {
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);     
    System.out.print("Enter a SIN: ");
String sinNumber = input.nextLine();

boolean validSin = 
        (sinNumber.length() == 11) && 
        (Character.isDigit(sinNumber.charAt(0))) &&
        (Character.isDigit(sinNumber.charAt(1))) &&
        (Character.isDigit(sinNumber.charAt(2))) &&
        (sinNumber.charAt(3) == '-') &&
        (Character.isDigit(sinNumber.charAt(4))) &&
        (Character.isDigit(sinNumber.charAt(5))) &&
        (Character.isDigit(sinNumber.charAt(7))) &&
        (sinNumber.charAt(6) == '-') &&
        (Character.isDigit(sinNumber.charAt(8))) &&
        (Character.isDigit(sinNumber.charAt(9))) &&
        (Character.isDigit(sinNumber.charAt(10)));

    if (validSin = true) { 
        String sinTwo = sinNumber.replace("-", "");         
    }
}
}
```

Do I need to multiply each number individually? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Pro tip: `if (something == true)` can always be shortened to `if (something)`

Comment: **should** always be

Comment: `validSin = true` is an assignment, not a truth check.

Comment: Have you considered parsing it as a number? E.g., `Long.parseLong`?

Comment: Doing math on a string is awfully painful.

Comment: Have you heard of regular expressions?

Comment: `if(validSin.matches("(\\d{3}-){2}\\d{3}"))`

Comment: if the answer if ok for you, think about accept it, or comment/edit your post o give further details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 steps in the method to follow ( [`Workable Demo`](https://ideone.com/F6soee) ):

1. Check the form, using a regular expression is the easiest way : group od 3 digits separated by a dash

   ```
   boolean validSin = sinNumber.matches("\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{3}");
   ```
2. Check the content

   - Take each digit one by one
   - if the digit is on odd index, multiply by 2
   - in case you're over 10, sum the 2 digits (`ex 16 -> 16/10 + 16%10 = 1+6 = 7`)
   - sum it all together
   - check if it's divisble by ten

   ```
   if (validSin) {
       String sinTwo = sinNumber.replace("-", "");
       int sum = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < sinTwo.length(); i++) {
           int digit = Character.getNumericValue(sinTwo.charAt(i));
           if (i % 2 != 0) {
               digit = digit * 2;
           }
           digit = digit / 10 + digit % 10;
           sum += digit;
       }
       validSin = sum % 10 == 0;
   }
   ```

---

By the way `if(validSin = true)` is not correct, it'll assign the value `true` to `validSin` and then evaluate the result : `true` always (primitive equals is done with `==`)

Comment: Why exactly do you only multiply if it's an odd index? 6 % 2 = 0, but 6 * 2 = 13, which requires addition. Shouldn't it be if ( i > 5)?

Comment: 121 212 121.. Notice that "2" is only located at ODD indices.. Multiplying by 1 is the same number so no need to do it.. Therefore he multiplied by 2 but only for odd indices because there's where it exists.. Then he does `digit = digit / 10 + digit % 10` which divides the number by 10 using integer division.. `13 / 10 = 1`. `13 % 10 = 3`.. He adds the `1 + 3` as per the requirement..

Comment: @TheHagerboy The formula is to multiply, digit by digit with 121212121 so event index multiply by 1, odd index by 2 take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Insurance_Number#Validation

Comment: My mistake, for some reason I thought that it took the number in the SIN, and not from what it was multiplied by.

Comment: @TheHagerboy If it's correct for you, I let you accept/vote up the answer ;)